# Best way to add a form to multiple pages?

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

I'm working on a project, that has a bunch of views with corresponding templates and forms. Every template contains a link to a login page (inherits it from the main template):

```
<ul class="options">
...
<li id="login">
   <a class="button" href="{% url 'forum:login' %}?next={{ request.path }}">Sign in</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

And it leads to a separate login page, that renders standard django login form.

I want to use jQuery to create or make visible that form on the same page where login link was clicked. What is the best way to add a form to multiple pages?

I've tried to get html and build a form dynamically with ajax:

**view:**

```
class Login(FormView):
...
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.is_ajax():
            form = self.get_form().as_ul()
            return HttpResponse(form)
        else:
            return super(Login, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

**script:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#login').on('click', 'a', function(event) {
    var loginUrl = $(this).attr('href');
    $.ajax({
       url: loginUrl,
       type: 'GET'})
    .done(function(html) {
         var newForm = $('<form/>', {action: loginUrl, method: 'post'});
         newForm.insertAfter('ul.options');
         newForm.append($('<input/>',
              {type: 'hidden', name: 'csrfmiddlewaretoken', value: csrftoken}));
         var newList = $('<ul/>');
         newForm.append(newList);
         newList.append(html);
         newList.append($('<li><input type="submit" value="Sign in"/></li>'));
    });
    event.preventDefault();
});
});
```

But I wonder, if there any better ways to complete such task?

Also I'm new to jQuery, so I'd appreciate any remarks on the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can put your form in it's own template loginform.html and then use "include" where you want it with:

```
{% include './path-to/loginform.html' %}
```

edit:
This is also a great way to handle things like your css and javascript areas, nav-menu, etc. [The Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#include)